# Im using a SAXParser and the Apostrof ( ' ) in <title> or <description> makeing problem

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am using SAXParser and the characters after any Apostrof(') in the xml file will not be printed i the listview? Anybody know why?

**Example:**

`<title>I'am a good Android programmer</title>`

The characters after "I'" will not bee printed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser may be overly sensetive to characters that may need escaping in certain situations. From what I can gather, apostrophes should not need escaping when it's part of the content, only when it's part of an attribute value. I tried it in an online XML validator, and it did agree with that.

Try to escape the apostrophes anyway:

```
<title>I&apos;am a good Android programmer</title>
```